# How to use oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory;

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic12c, osb

Somebody helps me with code example of proper using `oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`.
This is connection factory for using JMS through JMSAdapter in Weblogic 12C.
Weblogic 12С connected to standalone ActiveMQ server through JMSAdapter. In JMSAdapter I created new outbound connection with jndi eis/ext/open under oracle.tip.adapter.jms.IJmsConnectionFactory (interface) with properties:

```
AcknowledgeMode = AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE
ConnectionFactoryLocation = org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
FactoryProperties = BrockerURL=tcp://host:port;ThirdPartyJMSProvider=true
```

```java
public class CustomJMSSelector {

    private final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    private final static String JMS_FACTORY="eis/ext/open";
    private static JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;


    public static byte[] customSelectorConsumer(String correlationId) throws NamingException, ResourceException {

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

        jmsConnectionFactory = (JmsConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
```

I need to create session, consumer and consume message from queue using `oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`.

Unfortunately, oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory doesn't implement javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. It implements oracle.tip.adapter.jms.IJmsConnectionFactory that extends oracle.tip.adapter.api.OracleConnectionFactory. I tried cast to javax.jms.Connection or to org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory but got class cast exception. This connection is using by osb (proxy service, business service)

Comment: There is no feasible casting between those two factories, as you know, you should change the factory to weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory or weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory (or any that extends javax.jms.Connection, https://ora-soa.blogspot.com/2011/06/bpel-exception-caused-by-orabpel-20301.html

Comment: Hello. Under Deployments-> JMS Adapter in Weblogic Console
-> Under Configuration -> OutboundConnectionPool :
I have ConnectionFactoryLocation = org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory 
If i change it to weblogic.jms.XAConnectionFactory or weblogic.jms.ConnectionFactory my connection doen't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory` implements `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` you can simply create a connection, session, and consumer like so:

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
...

public class CustomJMSSelector {

    private final static String JNDI_FACTORY="weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    private final static String JMS_FACTORY="eis/ext/open";
    private final static String QUEUE_JNDI_NAME="queue/jndi/name";  // the JNDI name of the queue
    private static ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory;


    public static byte[] customSelectorConsumer(String correlationId) throws NamingException, ResourceException {
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

        jmsConnectionFactory = (JmsConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);
        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(QUEUE_JNDI_NAME);

        Connection connection = jmsConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        Message message = consumer.receive();
        // do something with the message
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

This is a *very* simple bit of code with no real resource management. In a production use-case you'd want to use a pooled connection factory so that you aren't actually creating and closing a physical connection for every message you receive.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately, oracle.tip.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory doesn't implement javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. It implements oracle.tip.adapter.jms.IJmsConnectionFactory that extends oracle.tip.adapter.api.OracleConnectionFactory. I tried cast to javax.jms.Connection but got class cast exception. That's why I decided to post question on stackoverflow

Comment: That information would be helpful in the question since it's a critical part of your problem.